# relative path using c#

Tags: c#, path, relative-path

I am using c#. In my project I am having a xml folder in which i have an xml file say "file.xml"..
I want to use the file in my project. I want to take that file from the current project itself,for that I am giving the path as:

```
  xmlDoc.Load(@"..\xml\file.xml");
```

but it is not taking the file.
It is showing some "C:" path..
how can I retrive this file from project itself.

Answer (score 6):

You should set the `Copy to Output Directory` property on the file in the Solution Explorer to gocpy the file to the folder with your EXE.

You can then write

```
xmlDoc.Load(Path.Combine(typeof(MyClass).Assembly, "file.xml"));
```

This uses the actual location of the EXE file and will work regardless of the current directory.

**EDIT**: In ASP.Net, you should put your file in the `App_Data` folder (which is not publicly accessible), then write

```
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/file.xml"));
```

Comment: In my case, this approach does not work because the Visual Studio Project containing the file is a SQL Database Project.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `Copy to Output Directory` to "copy if newer" and you can then use:

```
Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "file.xml");
```

Comment: it's not working..it is giving exception "file not found" and showing some "C:programfiles....." path.

Comment: Is it a windows app or ASP.NET app?

Comment: Try using 'Server.MapPath("~/file.xml");' The path will need to be relative.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.Combine(typeof(MyClass).Assembly.Location.ToString(), "file.xml")
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because `Location.ToString()` includes MyClass.exe